# SonarQube does not detect C# issues in Xamarin project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, sonarqube, static-analysis

I want to use SonarQube to analyze C# code of a Xamarin.Forms project with an Android and iOS app. For that I created a [demo app](https://github.com/ChristopherStephan/SonarQubeXamarinDemo) containing [code issues](https://github.com/ChristopherStephan/SonarQubeXamarinDemo/blob/master/SonarQube/SonarQube/SonarQube.cs) taken from the [SonarQube examples](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples/tree/master/sonarqube-scanner-msbuild/CSharpProject). However, these issues are not detected by SonarQube after scanning the code. What am I doing wrong?

I followed [these](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1441900) instructions and installed on macOS Sierra:

- SonarQube 6.7 LTS
- SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 4.0.1.883
- SonarC# analyzer plugin 6.7 (build 4267)

To build the project I use msbuild 15.2.0.0 that comes with Xamarin.

On the terminal I change my directory to `cd /SonarQubeXamarinDemo/SonarQube` and run the following commands.

```
mono /Users/christopher/Downloads/sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.0.1.883/MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"test" /d:sonar.host.url="http://localhost:9000" /d:sonar.login="***"


Default properties file was found at /Users/christopher/Downloads/sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.0.1.883/SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Loading analysis properties from /Users/christopher/Downloads/sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.0.1.883/SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Pre-processing started.
Preparing working directories...
15:14:24.778  Updating build integration targets...
15:14:24.796  Fetching analysis configuration settings...
15:14:25.164  Provisioning analyzer assemblies for cs...
15:14:25.165  Installing required Roslyn analyzers...
15:14:25.225  Pre-processing succeeded.

msbuild /t:Rebuild

...

mono /Users/christopher/Downloads/sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.0.1.883/MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end

SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 4.0.1
Default properties file was found at /Users/christopher/Downloads/sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.0.1.883/SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Loading analysis properties from /Users/christopher/Downloads/sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.0.1.883/SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Post-processing started.
SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS is not configured. Setting it to the default value of -Xmx1024m
Calling the SonarQube Scanner...
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /Users/christopher/Downloads/sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.0.1.883/sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: /Users/christopher/Documents/SonarQubeXamarinDemo/SonarQube/.sonarqube/out/sonar-project.properties
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.0.3.778
INFO: Java 1.8.0_91 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64
INFO: SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS=-Xmx1024m
INFO: User cache: /Users/christopher/.sonar/cache
INFO: Publish mode
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=92ms
INFO: Server id: AWBqDLDnW0cFaKeFAIpa
INFO: User cache: /Users/christopher/.sonar/cache
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=47ms
INFO: SonarQube server 6.7.0
INFO: Default locale: "de_DE", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Process project properties
INFO: Load project repositories
INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=104ms
INFO: Load quality profiles
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=28ms
INFO: Load active rules
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=418ms
INFO: Load metrics repository
INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=21ms
INFO: Project key: test
INFO: -------------  Scan SonarQube.iOS
INFO: Load server rules
INFO: Load server rules (done) | time=116ms
INFO: Base dir: /Users/christopher/Documents/SonarQubeXamarinDemo/SonarQube/iOS
INFO: Working dir: /Users/christopher/Documents/SonarQubeXamarinDemo/SonarQube/.sonarqube/out/.sonar/test_test_6E8E4F09-4D51-490F-A002-4E844C8CEC18
INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: de_DE
INFO: Index files
INFO: 0 files indexed
INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java]
INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java] (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files [php]
INFO: Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files [php] (done) | time=3ms
INFO: -------------  Scan SonarQube.Droid
INFO: Base dir: /Users/christopher/Documents/SonarQubeXamarinDemo/SonarQube/Droid
INFO: Working dir: /Users/christopher/Documents/SonarQubeXamarinDemo/SonarQube/.sonarqube/out/.sonar/test_test_E9EA7651-B0E9-4DAD-9256-A858860C4022
INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: de_DE
INFO: Index files
INFO: 0 files indexed
INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java]
INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java] (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files [php]
INFO: Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files [php] (done) | time=1ms
INFO: -------------  Scan SonarQube
INFO: Base dir: /Users/christopher/Documents/SonarQubeXamarinDemo/SonarQube/SonarQube
INFO: Working dir: /Users/christopher/Documents/SonarQubeXamarinDemo/SonarQube/.sonarqube/out/.sonar/test_test_9200C6D4-CA74-49DD-910F-6DAF012CCCDF
INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: de_DE
INFO: Index files
INFO: 0 files indexed
INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java]
INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java] (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files [php]
INFO: Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files [php] (done) | time=0ms
INFO: -------------  Scan test
INFO: Base dir: /Users/christopher/Documents/SonarQubeXamarinDemo/SonarQube
INFO: Working dir: /Users/christopher/Documents/SonarQubeXamarinDemo/SonarQube/.sonarqube/out/.sonar
INFO: Source paths: SonarQube/SonarQube.cs, SonarQube/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs, SonarQube/packages.config, iOS/Main.cs, iOS/AppDelegate.cs, iOS/Info.plist, iOS/Entitlements.plist, iOS/packages.config, Droid/MainActivity.cs, Droid/Resources/Resource.designer.cs, Droid/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs, Droid/Resources/AboutResources.txt, Droid/Properties/AndroidManifest.xml, Droid/Assets/AboutAssets.txt, Droid/packages.config
INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: de_DE
INFO: Index files
INFO: 15 files indexed
INFO: Quality profile for cs: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for xml: Sonar way
INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp]
INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp] (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java]
WARNING: WARN: Property missing: 'sonar.cs.analyzer.projectOutPaths'. No protobuf files will be loaded for this project.
WARNING: WARN: No roslyn issues report not found for this project.
INFO: 1 source files to be analyzed
INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java] (done) | time=62ms
INFO: 1/1 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Sensor XML Sensor [xml]
INFO: Sensor XML Sensor [xml] (done) | time=211ms
INFO: Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files [php]
INFO: Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files [php] (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Sensor C# [csharp]
INFO: Sensor C# [csharp] (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=11ms
INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer
INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=0ms
INFO: SCM provider for this project is: git
INFO: 8 files to be analyzed
INFO: 0/8 files analyzed
WARNING: WARN: Missing blame information for the following files:
WARNING: WARN:   * Droid/MainActivity.cs
WARNING: WARN:   * Droid/Properties/AndroidManifest.xml
WARNING: WARN:   * Droid/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
WARNING: WARN:   * Droid/Resources/Resource.designer.cs
WARNING: WARN:   * SonarQube/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
WARNING: WARN:   * SonarQube/SonarQube.cs
WARNING: WARN:   * iOS/AppDelegate.cs
WARNING: WARN:   * iOS/Main.cs
WARNING: WARN: This may lead to missing/broken features in SonarQube
INFO: Calculating CPD for 0 files
INFO: CPD calculation finished
INFO: Analysis report generated in 99ms, dir size=216 KB
INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 19ms, zip size=37 KB
INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 48ms
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/test
INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
INFO: More about the report processing at http://localhost:9000/api/ce/task?id=AWBvIYbsCU-ClqGI-H2t
INFO: Task total time: 3.392 s
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 4.593s
INFO: Final Memory: 49M/401M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
The SonarQube Scanner has finished
15:15:56.62  Creating a summary markdown file...
15:15:56.627  Analysis results: http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/test
15:15:56.628  Post-processing succeeded.
```

The report does not show any detected issues:

[image]

I noticed these warnings but do not know if they are relevant for the undetected code issues:

```
WARNING: WARN: Property missing: 'sonar.cs.analyzer.projectOutPaths'. No protobuf files will be loaded for this project.
WARNING: WARN: No roslyn issues report not found for this project.
```

What I tried so far to fix the issue without succeeding

- setting the language to C# using `/d:sonar.language=cs`

Comment: I found [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/111935/source-code-analysis-for-xamarin-project-with-sonarqube-on-mac/p1?new=1) in the Xamarin forum. May it could help you.

Comment: Thanks, I reviewed that and cannot find a difference to my setup.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. so I changed the approach as below:

`sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.0.1.883\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:FAM
dotnet restore
dotnet build
sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.0.1.883\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end`

So instead of using msbuild.exe you can use dotnet cli commands.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to build the Xamarin project using `dotnet` but it turned out that it does not support Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android. I am getting the same error as described [here](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6011).